# JPA2.0/Hibernate with Native Query - getResultList() is slow when multiple rows are returnred

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA2.0 and Hibernate as ORM. I am trying to fetch a table data which can have millions of records. I have written native query and trying to fetch it using JPA2.0/Hibernate.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select empId, empName, empDepart from employee");
final List<Object[]> stList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
for (Object[] objects : stList) {
     // Fetching data and putting into my VOs here
}
```

When I enabled the hibernate logging, below logs are printed. What is happening here is this query is returning arround 5000 rows and if you see below logs "result row:" is printed one by one till all 5000 rows fetched. It is taking almost 3-4 minute to complete. Is there any faster way to load all 5000 records in JPA/Hibernate. Any Idea please ?

```
2015-03-11 15:51:01,850 DEBUG - begin
2015-03-11 15:51:01,850 DEBUG - opening JDBC connection
2015-03-11 15:51:04,026 DEBUG - current autocommit status: true
2015-03-11 15:51:04,026 DEBUG - disabling autocommit
2015-03-11 15:51:04,057 DEBUG - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2015-03-11 15:51:04,059 DEBUG - Select empId, empName, empDepart from employee
2015-03-11 15:51:04,627 DEBUG - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
2015-03-11 15:51:04,632 DEBUG - result row: 
2015-03-10 19:14:11,614 DEBUG - result row: 
2015-03-10 19:14:11,614 DEBUG - result row: 
2015-03-10 19:14:11,615 DEBUG - result row: 
.
. 
.
2015-03-11 15:53:51,950 DEBUG - result row: 
2015-03-11 15:53:51,950 DEBUG - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
2015-03-11 15:53:51,950 DEBUG - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2015-03-11 15:53:51,951 DEBUG - initializing non-lazy collections
2015-03-11 15:53:51,952 DEBUG - rollback
2015-03-11 15:53:52,189 DEBUG - re-enabling autocommit
2015-03-11 15:53:52,189 DEBUG - rolled back JDBC Connection
2015-03-11 15:53:52,190 DEBUG - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
2015-03-11 15:53:52,190 DEBUG - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2015-03-11 15:53:52,445 INFO  - closing
```

Comment: Are you really needed over 1M records in same time? On my opinion ORM is not designed for this tasks.

Comment: Not really 1M..but its around 10000 records which I load into cache at very first request then use it from cache itself. But, first request itself delayed due to loading these records.

Comment: Time needed by the query is just the time needed for executing `query.getResultList()`. How long does that take? Printing out `result row:` happens in the loop when the query is finished, and judging by the logs packing the results in your DTOs takes almost 3 minutes.

Comment: The cache - is good solution. I suppose you are using 2LC? If you are using cache 3-5-10 minutes is reasonable fee for your task. But you must switch (convert) query to HQL.

Comment: @Predrag Maric: Actually maximum time goes when loop is started. So time is going in parsing the result. If I run my query on TOAD, it takes hardly 300 ms. But when I run as shown above, takes almost 3-4 minutes where mostly time is taken in parsing the result.

Comment: So the question is if the parsing code can be optimized. You should either edit the question title and post the parsing code, or ask a new question.